# Self join(hierarchical data) in Hibernate-search

Tags: hibernate-search

I have two fields in an entity:

- id
- parentId

I want a self-join to fetch (hierarchical data) the childrens of parent id.
Something like oracle [Hierarchical Queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Hibernate Search does expose runtime joins capabilities.

If your goal is to order results "parents first", I think you may be able to create a getter that creates a string similar to "rootId.grandParentId.parentId.thisId", and index the result of that getter. Then you can sort on that string. That would clearly be a hack, but it may work.

Alternatively, you may be able to leverage native join capabilities of Lucene or Elasticsearch within Hibernate Search But that will require extensive knowledge of Lucene or Elasticsearch.

With Hibernate Search 5, you may be able to implement it for Lucene, but probably not for Elasticsearch. Unforunately, documentation of Lucene features is sparse.

With Hibernate Search 6, you may be able to implement it in both cases.
You will need:

- native fields ([Lucene](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-lucene-field-types-extension)/[ES](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-elasticsearch-field-types-extension))
- [native predicates](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-extensions)
- obviously a good deal of knowledge of advanced Lucene/Elasticsearch features. For Lucene, documentation is sparse. For Elasticsearch, here is a good place to start: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html